# Putting displacement between circles

Tags: actionscript-3, math, actionscript

I would like to set a displacement between the circles that are drawn here. Besides, I would like to copy the circles positions to the head circle, but the offset of course is cleared due to that.

```
public var circles:Vector.<circle> = new Vector.<circle>(5);
        public function t()
        {

        var offset:int = 10;    
        for ( var i:int = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            var c:circle = new circle();

            c.xPosition= 120+offset;
            c.yPosition = 120;
            c.vx = 1;
            c.vy = 0;
            circles[i] = c;
            offset+=40;


        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);

        }

        public function gameLoop(event:Event):void
        {
            for ( var i:int = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
                addChild(circles[i]);
                circles[i].drawCircle(circles[i].xPosition, circles[i].yPosition);
            }


            for ( var i:int = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
                if ( i != 0 )
                {
                circles[i].xPosition = circles[i-1].xPosition;
                circles[i].yPosition = circles[i-1].yPosition;
                }
                else {

                }
            }

            circles[0].xPosition-=circles[0].vx*(2*5);
            circles[0].yPosition-=circles[0].vy*(2*5);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the loop from back to front. What you did change every circle's position same with circle 0

```
 for ( var i:int = 4; i > 0; i--)
 {   
      circles[i].xPosition = circles[i-1].xPosition;
      circles[i].yPosition = circles[i-1].yPosition;

  }
```

Comment: the snake or the circles move so fast, depending on the number that the velocity is multiplied. I would like to the snake to move slower, but still the displacement should be far enough, that doesn't affect the speed of the snake.